# SelectMany linq multiple collections from the base same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have an object that has many `collections`

```
public class Person
{
 public int id {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Address> Address {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Job> Job {get; set;}
}

   public class Adress
    {
     public bool IsCurrent {get; set;}
    }
public class Job
    {
     public bool IsCurrent {get; set;}
    }
```

A person can have a `list of addresses` but only one is current, and a `list of Jobs` but only one is current.

I need to write a `linq to sql` Entity Framework query where I select the person where `Id= 1` and get the `current job and current address`.

Then select then select some fields from `person, current address and current job`.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Your model is not complete, the little code you did provide is of no real help and will not even compile, and you included no attempt to solve your own problem.

Comment: Yes, you should also show Job and Address entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Job` and `Address` have a boolean field called `IsCurrent`.

```
using (YourDbContext context = new YourDbContext()) {
    int id = 1;
    var results = (from person in context.People
                   where person.Id == id
                   select new {
                       Person = person,
                       CurrentJob = person.Job.FirstOrDefault(j => j.IsCurrent),
                       CurrentAddress = person.Address.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsCurrent)
                   });
}
```

You can change the anonymous object to anything that suits you.

Comment: Yes, a little more information would have been valuable, but I guess Job and Address entities must have a boolean flag or something like that, it's the usual way to do it :)

Comment: @jorgonor - just a little improvement - Replace the `Where().FirstOrDefault` just with `FirstOrDefault` and the predicate

Comment: @GiladGreen I didn't know that one! It's less verbose like this, I like it!

Comment: @jorgonor - Cool :) Now it is like what I was about to post :) You got there before me